# SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

when i click on the following link i get javascript error :

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
```

**Through firebug :**

---

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="SubmitWithLog('HR','https://hr.test/hr/index.aspx?enc=ae%734II-.l%60%22%2c%sm67%1b'%3546bnv%2b!%1tyu)MQR%780%01%16LVWP%3b0M7ghnz%ef%bf%523jd%3b','#ctl273')" id="ctl562_ctrl11_hl_sys">HR</a>
```

---

**My .cs:**

```
 void hl_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
                {
                    HtmlGenericControl hl = (HtmlGenericControl)sender;

                    hl.InnerText = ((hl.NamingContainer as RadListViewDataItem).DataItem as DataRowView)["name"].ToString().TrimEnd();

                    string winURL = ((hl.NamingContainer as RadListViewDataItem).DataItem as DataRowView)["url"].ToString().TrimEnd();

                    HashSet<string> frmId = ((HashSet<string>)parent.Context.Session["blocks"]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < frmId.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (frmId.ElementAt(i).Split('|')[1] == winURL)
                        {
                            hl.Attributes["onclick"] = "SubmitWithLog('" + hl.InnerText + "'" + "," + "'" + frmId.ElementAt(i).Split('|')[1] + frmId.ElementAt(i).Split('|')[2] + "'" + "," + "'#" + frmId.ElementAt(i).Split('|')[0].Trim() + "')";
                            hl.Attributes["href"] = "javascript:void(0)";
                            break;
                        }

                    }


                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the second parameter stops early?

```
'HR','https://hr.test/hr/index.aspx?enc=ae%734II-.l%60%22%2c%sm67%1b'
```

I.e. there's a single quote character there inside the string.

Comment: yea , but how to fix the problem !!

Comment: Escape the character within the CS file, like so: hl.Attributes["onclick"] = "SubmitWithLog('" + hl.InnerText + "'" + "," + "'" + frmId.ElementAt(i).Split('|')[1].Replace("'", "\'") + frmId.ElementAt(i).Split('|')[2].Replace("'", "\'") + "'" + "," + "'#" + frmId.ElementAt(i).Split('|')[0].Trim().Replace("'", "\'") + "')";